# Up, down, left, right

Tags: knowledge, language, cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Right**
1. Stop behind fashionable content (6)
4. Wingspan is chosen to cover language for left clues (8)
10. Former students crossed feet and consumed metal compounds (9)
11. Six losses to start with? Getting to grips with the Yankees' home record (5)
12/17. I give out broken Segas to get fluid, in theory (7,3)
14. Conducting odd drift around a European capital (7)
15. Bendy gent goes around India and bends (5)
16. Kidney bean's last seen west of Erie, moving (5)
17. (*See 12*)

**Left**
18. Radiation from black light grape (3)
19. Survey to return Dutch artist's missing piece (5)
20. Very heavy inhabitants of those Bosnian retreats (5)
21. Farmer's language for down clues (7)
23. The fate of Van Gogh, you and I: Drowned in acids, perhaps (7)
24. Hero botches stuffing machine (5)
25. Represent in words baby's bed being surrounded by endless longing (9)
31. A sign of twitchiness is thanks to a Greek movement's follower (8)
34. Deserter finally found in Florida city – it's a trap (6)

**Down**
1. Language for up clues and two horror films (7)
2. He has almost a whole euro, and a bit of time (5)
3. Norse god not beginning to know the law (3)
5. Take public relations against goal, resolve case (7)
6. Modify a contract held by Colombian overlord (5)
7. Young sage rebuilt house of worship (9)
8. "Crazy Eli" shot serfs in ancient Sparta (7)
9. Mother's working home (6)
13. Parcel out the top of Isengard in *The Lord of the Rings* (5)

**Up**
22. One single describing Great Britain and Ireland, perhaps (5)
26. Mob leader missing; half of LAPD to be depressed at the top and bottom (6)
27. Creative person's heart is taken in secret (7)
28. In Mexico, what thing essentially follows confused scuba divers? (9)
29. Chat in the middle of California, approximately (5)
30. Fixed fare fit the costs (7)
32. Through the central pieces in opera (3)
33. Very stubborn animal with artificial intelligence (5)
34. Theodore leading escape near one of Mexico's borders, making language for right clues (7)

Comment: 16r says (6) but the space (and indeed the solution) is (5).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Oops! Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: I think there is something subtly wrong with 1d (but it doesn't really matter).

Comment: (Also, I might well be wrong. There is at least one thing about how this works that I don't understand yet.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What a magnificent puzzle! There is a very special novelty to it, in that:

> Right clues are written in **German**;
>  Left clues are written in **Spanish**;
>  Down clues are written in **French**;
>  and Up clues are written in **Italian**.

Here is the completed grid:

> [image]

Cryptic clue explanations (I've tried to do the shorthand but bear with me - I'm still learning it!):

> **Right**
>  1. Stop behind fashionable content (6) **IN + HALT** [content – German]
>  4. Wingspan is chosen to cover language for left clues (8) **_SPANISCH_** [language for left clues – German]
>  10. Former students crossed feet and consumed metal compounds (9) **ALUM(NI)* + ATE** [metal compounds – German]
>  11. Six losses to start with? Getting to grips with the Yankees' home record (5) **VI + NY + L(osses)** [record – German]
>  12/17. I give out broken Segas to get fluid, in theory (7,3) **I + DEAL + (SEGAS)*** [fluid, in theory – German]
>  14. Conducting odd drift around a European capital (7) **D_I_(RIGA)T** [conducting – German]
>  15. Bendy gent goes around India and bends (5) **(GENT + I)** [bends – German]
>  16. Kidney bean's last seen west of Erie, moving (5) **(bea)N + (ERIE)*** [Kidney – German]
>  17. *(See 12)*
>
>  **Left**
>  18. Radiation from black light grape (3) **ddef** [Radiation from black light / Grape – Spanish]
>  19. Survey to return Dutch artist's missing piece (5) **TO< + EAR** [Survey – Spanish]
>  20. Very heavy inhabitants of those Bosnian retreats (5) **_OSEBO_<** [Very heavy – Spanish]
>  21. Farmer's language for down clues (7) **ddef** [(Actress) Farmer / language for down clues – Spanish]
>  23. The fate of Van Gogh, you and I: Drowned in acids, perhaps (7)  **(U + I + ACIDS)*** [The fate of Van Gogh – Spanish]
>  24. Hero botches stuffing machine (5)  **_ROBOT_** [machine – Spanish]
>  25. Represent in words baby's bed being surrounded by endless longing (9) **DES(CRIB)IR_** [Represent in words – Spanish]
>  31. A sign of twitchiness is thanks to a Greek movement's follower (8) **A + TIC + IS + TA** [Greek movement’s follower – Spanish]
>  34. Deserter finally found in Florida city – it's a trap (6) **T(_R)AMPA** [trap – Spanish]
>
>  **Down**
>  1. Language for up clues and two horror films (7) **IT + ALIEN** [Language for up clues – French]
>  2. He has almost a whole euro, and a bit of time (5) **H(EUR_)E** [a bit of time – French]
>  3. Norse god not beginning to know the law (3) **LO(k)I** [the law – French]
>  5. Take public relations against goal, resolve case (7)  **PR + END + R(esolv)E** [take – French]
>  6. Modify a contract held by Colombian overlord (5) **_NOVER_** [Modify a contract – French]
>  7. Young sage rebuilt house of worship (9) **(YOUNG SAGE)*** [house of worship – French]
>  8. "Crazy Eli" shot serfs in ancient Sparta (7) **(ELI SHOT)*** [serfs in ancient Sparta – French]
>  9. Mother's working home (6) **MA + IS + ON** [home – French]
>  13. Parcel out the top of Isengard in *The Lord of the Rings* (5) **LOT(I)R** [Parcel out – French]
>
>  **Up**
>  22. One single describing Great Britain and Ireland, perhaps (5) **I + SOLE** [Great Britain and Irelans, perhaps – Italian]
>  26. Mob leader missing; half of LAPD to be depressed at the top and bottom (6) **(m)OB + LA(pd) + TO** [depressed at the top and bottom – Italian]
>  27. Creative person's heart is taken in secret (7) **_ARTISTA_** [Creative person – Italian]
>  28. In Mexico, what thing essentially follows confused scuba divers? (9) **(SCUBA)* + QUE + (th)I(ng)** [divers – Italian]
>  29. Chat in the middle of California, approximately (5) **C(IRC)A** [approximately – Italian]
>  30. Fixed fare fit the costs (7) **(FARE FIT)*** [costs – Italian]
>  32. Through the central pieces in opera (3) **_PER_** [Through – Italian]
>  33. Very stubborn animal with artificial intelligence (5) **ASS + AI** [Very – Italian]
>  34. Theodore leading escape near one of Mexico's borders, making language for right clues (7) **TED + ESC + (mexic)O** [language for right clues – Italian]

Comment: Bah! Ninjaed because I (1) bothered to make explanations, (2) was trying to figure out what to do with the right-hand grid before posting anything, and (3) finished _all_ the clues before posting an answer.

Comment: (I still haven't figured out what to do with the right-hand grid.)

Comment: Ah, sorry @GarethMcCaughan! The right-hand grid is just the same as the left, just rotated 180 degrees, so it allows you to orientate the clues which are reversed in the left-hand one to see them the right way round.

Comment: How do you know that's all it's for? I mean, it _could_ be, but how do you know there isn't some final extraction step that uses it somehow? (I tried overlaying the original grid on its 180-degree rotation, since that seemed like it might be indicated, but nothing useful came of it.)

Comment: It just strikes me as purely for aesthetic convenience. The puzzle is one of @jafe's weekly cryptics so I don't think there's anything more than just a brilliant theme...

Comment: You might well be right. But we already know that this is a _different_ crossword -- it has the reversed clues and the multiple languages.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Hmm, sorry, I should have probably added an explanation about the second grid. That's indeed there only for convenience (being able to read left and up clues the "right" way while filling the grid).

Answer (score 8):

Grid:

> [image]

Explanations:

Right clues: These are in TEDESCO (German).

> 1r. Def "content"; HALT after IN.
>  4r. Def "language for left clues"; substring of "wingspan is chosen".
>  10r. Def "metal compounds"; ALUMNI with "feet" NI interchanged plus ATE.
>  11r. Def "record"; VI + L containing NY.
>  12,17r. Def "fluid, in theory"; I DEAL + SEGAS*.
>  14r. Def "conducting"; D(-r)I(-f)T around RIGA.
>  15r. Def "bends"; GENT* round I.
>  16r. Def "kidney"; (-bea)N west of ERIE*.

Left clues: These are in SPANISCH (Spanish).

> 18l. Double def; UV-A and grape.
>  19l. Def "survey"; I didn't get the wordplay but Stiv did: it's TO< + (van Gogh's) EAR.
>  20l. Def "very heavy"; reversed substring of "those Bosnian".
>  21l. Double def; "Farmer" (Frances Farmer, actress) and "language for down clues".
>  23l. Def "the fate of Van Gogh"; UI in ACIDS*.
>  24l. Def "machine"; substring of "hero botches".
>  25l. Def "represent in words"; CRIB in DESIR(-e).
>  31l. Def "a Greek movement's follower"; A TIC IS TA.
>  34l. Def "a trap"; (-deserte)R in TAMPA.

Down clues: These are in FRANCES (French).

> 1d. Double def; "language for up clues" and there are two horror movies called "The Italian". (I'm not sure whether this should have ITALIEN in the grid, violating the principle that wordplay is in English, or ITALIAN in the grid, violating the principle that solutions are in the given language. I've gone with the former.)
>  2d. Def "a bit of time"; HE containing EUR(-o).
>  3d. Def "the law"; LOKI minus K(-now).
>  5d. Def "take"; PR + END + R(esolv)E.
>  6d. Def "modify a contract"; substring of "Colombian overlord".
>  7d. Def "house of worship"; YOUNGSAGE*.
>  8d. Def "serfs in ancient Sparta"; ELISHOT*.
>  9d. Def "home"; MA IS ON.
>  13d. Def "parcel out"; I(-sengard) in LOTR.

Up clues: These are in ITALIEN (Italian).

> 22u. Def "Great Britain and Ireland, perhaps"; I + SOLE.
>  26u. Def "depressed at the top and bottom"; (-m)OB + LA(-pd) + TO.
>  27u. Def "creative person"; substring of "heart is taken".
>  28u. Def "divers"; QUE + (-th)I(-ng) after SCUBA*.
>  29u. Def "approximately"; IRC in CA.
>  30u. Def "the costs"; FAREFIT*.
>  32u. Def "through"; (-o)PER(-a).
>  33u. Def "very"; ASS + AI.
>  34u. Def "language for right clues"; TED ESC (-mexic)O.

Comment: 19L is rot13('GB' erirefrq naq "Qhgpu negvfg'f zvffvat cvrpr" vf n ersrerapr gb Ina Tbtu'f RNE)

Comment: Ah, very nice! So in fact you finished it before I did. Though I had all the _words_ before you posted your answer :-).

Comment: Well done for getting your explanations down first - the write-up is the part I find hardest as I'm still not entirely au fait with the shorthand...

Comment: I write my explanations as I solve the clues, so the solution takes a little longer but there isn't a separate explanation-writing step.